# Dump SVN repository via SSH - because of space limitations

Tags: ssh, svn

I'm trying to cleanup space on my server so I don't have to pay outrageous hosting fees. My SVN repo is 16G so I'm going to pull that and put it on my local machine. I'm currently at 66% space on my server and backing up my repo puts me over 100% which kills the svn dump. Can I perform a backup over SSH to my local machine?

**The Dump Command**

```
$ sudo svnadmin dump /var/repo > repo.svn_dump
```

**SSH Dump Attempt** *from local machine - failed*

```
$ sudo svnadmin dump http://jackson@xxxxx.com/var/repo > repo.svn_dump
svnadmin: E205000: 'http://jackson@xxxxx.com/var/repo' is a URL when it should be a local path
```

======

## Solution

```
$ ./svnrdump dump http://jackson@xxxxx.com/var/repo > ~/repo.svn_dump
```

Notes:

- I ran this local from my machine (osx 10.11.4)
- I had to chase down the mac specific install of `svnrdump` which is installed with Xcode Command Line Tools
- Find out how to do this [here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/)
- If you're on Linux this process is likely a lot easier..

Comment: Try: `scp username@yourUrl.com:/var/repo /path/to/destination/on/local/machine`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like recent versions of SVN provide an `svnrdump` utility that is designed for exactly this purpose. From the [Repository Maintenance](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html) section of the [Red Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)

> The svnrdump program is, to put it simply, essentially just network-aware flavors of the svnadmin dump and svnadmin load subcommands, rolled up into a separate program.

Basic usage would be something like

```
svnrdump dump http://jackson@xxxxx.com/var/repo > repo.svn_dump
```